# R can't drop NA columns , tried several approaches

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a column with dates. the file is exported from an excel format.

```
summary(u$date)

                 Min.               1st Qu.                Median                  Mean               3rd Qu.                  Max. 
"2012-01-13 00:00:00" "2014-05-14 00:00:00" "2015-04-09 00:00:00" "2015-05-03 17:58:04" "2016-03-03 00:00:00" "2018-06-11 00:00:00" 
                 NA's 
               "5748"
```

I tried the following:

```
u%>%drop_na(`date`)

u<-u[!is.na(u$`date`),]
```

Unfortunately it has no effect and the number of rows does not get smaller.
Where am I going wrong ?

i clearly want to drop the columns with NA

Comment: ‘na.omit(u)’ is another one. Did you visually inspect the data in R? Or confirm a value is NA with ‘is.na()’? Sometimes when I think R is not working properly it’s actually because I am not working properly!

Answer (score 2):

try `drop_na(u, date)`

you can also try base R approach -

`u[!is.na(u$date), ]`

Comment: Could you explain the bug with `drop_na` ?